# Choose multiple values from multiple rows and columns from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have a matrix

```
A = [1, 2, 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

If I want to choose say (1,2), (2,3)

I could not say A(1:2,2:3) otherwise it will return a 2*2 matrix, what should I do it for only one time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`sub2ind`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to linearly index (to avoid creating a matrix) using the given row and column numbers -

```
ind = [1,2;2,3]
A(sub2ind(size(A),ind(:,1),ind(:,2)))
```